# How can I do OAuth authorization code in LWC to get the code in same page?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, community

I am creating a component to connect salesforce to dropbox and I am not able to get the code in parent window as I am opening a new window for authorization URL using window.open() and storing its instance in a variable. Now it redirects and shows the code but how can I get it on my parent window so I can call to get the access token?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava opening the authorization URL from the component on button click in a new window using window.open and storing its instance. Then using that to get the URL with code included in it by instance.location.href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the page parameters using `lighting-navigation` [module](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) once you land off to a lightning page with URL parameters that has auth code.

The below code should help

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class MyComponentName extends LightningElement {

 currentPageReference = null; 
 urlStateParameters = null;

/* Params from Url */
Id = null;

@wire(CurrentPageReference)
getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
   if (currentPageReference) {
      this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference.state;
      this.setParametersBasedOnUrl();
   }
}

 setParametersBasedOnUrl() {
   this.Id = this.urlStateParameters.id || null;
  }
}
```

From there write an apex class that makes `HTTP` post [request](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts) with the auth code.

Comment: where should I pass my URL where I need to redirect after the authorization?

Comment: It is better to redirect to an app page that is created for this purpose or a visualforce page! With vf page you have to pass the token to the lwc component using post messages!

Comment: I don't want to create a  VF page that's why trying to get the code directly into the LWC for API calls. Having no luck in this haha.

Comment: @MridulKapil: Did you find any correct way of doing this ? If yes can you let me know I wanted to set up an integration , i have created an app in the target system but not sure what redirect uri I wil be providing. thnx